# Relatively compact sequence of Borel measures which is not asymptotically tight

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I am trying to find a sequence of Borel measures on a metric space that is relatively compact but not asymptotically tight. Asymptotic tightness of a net (or sequence) of functions is defined in van der Waart's *Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes* as:

> The net of functions $X_{\alpha}$ (defined on a space $D$) is *aymptotically tight* if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that
>   $$ \liminf P_*(X_{\alpha} \in K^{\delta}) \geq 1-\epsilon \quad \textrm{for every 
> $\delta>0$}$$ 
>   where $K^{\delta} = \{y \in D: d(y,K)<\delta\}$.

In this definition it is not assumed that $X_{\alpha}$ is measurable, so the $P_*$ appearing there is the so-called *inner probability*. However the question I'm interested in concerns only Borel measures so this doesn't matter.

This is actually an Exercise in van der Waart's book, and he gives a long hint but I am fairly sure the argument is wrong. I reproduce the hint here. Note $\ell^{\infty}(D)$ is the space of all bounded functions on $D$ equipped with the sup norm $\|z\|_{D} = \sup_{x \in D} |z(x)|$.

> For every rational $q$, let $L_q$ be the measure on $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{Q})$ with $L_q(\{0\}) = L_q(\{z_q\}) = 1/2$, where 0 is the function that is identically zero and $z_q$ is the function that is zero except at the point $q$, where it is 1. Take a sequence $\{q_n: n = 1, 2, \ldots \}$ of rational numbers that reaches every rational number infinitely often, e.g. $0, 1, -1, 0, 1/2, -1/2, 1, -1, 3/2, -3/2, 2, -2, 0, 1/3, \ldots$ Then the sequence $L_{q_n}$ has all measures $L_q$ as weak limit points, and it is relatively compact. If the sequence were asymptotically tight, then it would be uniformly tight (in the old sense), because every $L_q$ is tight. But there is no compact $K$ with $L_q(K) > 3/4$ for every $q$. Indeed, $K$ would have to contain both 0 and $z_q$ for every $q$, which is impossible since $\|z_q - z_r\| = 1$ forevery pair of distinct rationals $q, r$.

Unless I am mistaken the sequence of rationals he gives is not actually relatively compact. Take for example the sequence $0, 1, 2, \ldots$. Or even any sequence that does not eventually become constant--by the last statement of the hint.

But I'm having trouble thinking of an example that works here. Any ideas?